# Handling variable special characters in python from pulled HTML pages

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii

When I get html data using Mechanize, I store this into a variable, let's call it "HTML_RESPONSE". Once this is done, I then parse it and extract three things:
Title, Short Description and Long Description.

The problem I am facing is where the short or long description have the potential of containing characters such as - &, £, $ and so forth.

The problem arises when I try to put this into an XML and save it, since python freaks out when I try to decode these.

For example here is a short description from the page:

```
S_DESC = "Senior VP of Treasury and Corporate Finance & ERM, 
RTL Group, has been invited to the above conference to present a Case Study 
on Integrating Strategy and Risk into Enterprise Risk Management"
```

The way I am decoding -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-

print S_DESC.decode('UTF-8').encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace')
```

This works fine on ampersands.
If I then get a S_DESC with a pound sterling sign, my script breaks with this output:

**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3'**

Where this code fails in the portion of my script (the above exception is thrown in the very last line, every time I get a pound sterling sign). I would like to know if there is a universal way of telling python to just handle these chars on it's own.
Making 100 functions for each possible incompatible character is not an option, in the same way, I am not prepared to sift through the whole website (2k + articles) in order to identify all special characters that "might" throw my code off....

```
XML = """
    <MAIN>
        <ITEM>
            <Author>{0}</Author>
            <Author_UN>{1}</Author_UN>
            <Date_Modified>{2}</Date_Modified>
            <Date_Published>{3}</Date_Published>
            <Default_Group_Rights>
                {4}
            </Default_Group_Rights>
            <attachment>
                <file_name>{5}</file_name>
                <file_extension>{6}</file_extension>
                <file_stored_local>{7}</file_stored_local>
            </attachment>
            <title>{8}</title>
            <sm_desc>{9}</sm_desc>
            <lg_desc>
                <![CDATA[
                {10}
                ]]>
            </lg_desc>
        </ITEM>
    </MAIN>""".format(author_soup,  username,  date_modified,  published_date,  xrights,  attachment_text,  file_extension,  localstore,  item_title.decode('UTF-8').encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace'), short_description.decode('UTF-8').encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace'),  long_description.decode('UTF-8').encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace'))
```

## [EDIT]

This is a sample code I created which reflects the error perfectly, just in case someone wan't to have a swing at this?

```
    #TESTING GROUND
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

author_soup = "John Smith"
username = "jsmith"
date_modified = "25 December 2012, 15:42 PM"
published_date = "25 December 2012, 15:42 PM"
xrights = "r-w-x-x"
attachment_text = "Random Attachment"
file_extension = "txt"
localstore = "../Local"
item_title = "The NEw Financial Reforms of 2012"
short_description = " £16 Billion Spent on new reforms backfire."
long_description = '[<p>fullstory</p>, <p><a class="external-link" href="http://business.timesonline.co.uk/tol/business/industry_sectors/banking_and_finance/article4526065.ece">http://business.timesonline.co.uk/tol/business/industry_sectors/banking_and_finance/article4526065.ece</a></p>]'

XML = """
<MAIN>
    <ITEM>
        <Author>{0}</Author>
        <Author_UN>{1}</Author_UN>
        <Date_Modified>{2}</Date_Modified>
        <Date_Published>{3}</Date_Published>
        <Default_Group_Rights>
            {4}
        </Default_Group_Rights>
        <attachment>
            <file_name>{5}</file_name>
            <file_extension>{6}</file_extension>
            <file_stored_local>{7}</file_stored_local>
        </attachment>
        <title>{8}</title>
        <sm_desc>{9}</sm_desc>
        <lg_desc>
            <![CDATA[
            {10}
            ]]>
        </lg_desc>
    </ITEM>
</MAIN>""".format(author_soup,  username,  date_modified,  published_date,  xrights,  attachment_text,  file_extension,  localstore,  item_title.decode('UTF-8'), short_description.decode('UTF-8'),  long_description.decode('UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Why do you want to use ASCII? XML supports Unicode just fine. You just need to encode `"`, `<`, `>`, and `&`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to accomplish this? I am not tied down to ascii at all, i just want it to work.
How would I encode these characters and where? Would you be able to provide with a sample code using this sentence i used on an earlier comment as a variable: '£1,000,000 spent on Reform & Change Management' <-- it has both chars in one place, so I think it is better for testing the outcome.

Comment: Since you're decoding from UTF-8 (a unicode encoding), it is already in unicode.  Why are you trying to do this at all?

Comment: FYI, here's a good introduction to unicode.  It was only after reading this that I really understood it! http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: thank you. I will definitely have a look. I need to understand this, since it is driving me absolutely mad...